# Multiple case in mysql is not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the below code but it is not working for me.

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.service_id,t2.provider_name ,t3.id,t3.api_name,t4.id, t4.member_no,
    (
        CASE t1.status WHEN 0 THEN 'Success'
                       WHEN 1 THEN 'Failed'
                       WHEN 4 THEN 'Hold/InQueue'
                       WHEN 6 THEN 'Pending'
                       WHEN 9 THEN 'Error'
    ) AS status1,
    (
        CASE t1.stv WHEN 0 THEN 'TopUp'
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'scheme' END
    ) AS scheme
FROM tbl_mobile_recharge t1 INNER JOIN tbl_service_providers t2 
    ON t1.opcode = t2.id
INNER JOIN tbl_mobile_api_master t3
    ON t1.api_id = t3.id
INNER JOIN tbl_retailer t4
    ON t1.user_id = t4.id
WHERE 1=1 AND t1.added_on >='2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND t1.added_on <='2016-03-11 23:59:59'
    AND 1=1 AND 1=1
ORDER BY t1.id DESC
LIMIT 0,8
```

And I am getting this **error** below.

> A Database Error Occurred         Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds  to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near ') as status1,(case
>   t1.stv when 0 then  'TopUp' when 1 then 'scheme' end ) as sche' at
>   line 1

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Your first case statement is missing it's "end".  Might also want to add defaults in.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `END` marker in your first `CASE` statement.  Try using this instead:

```
CASE t1.status WHEN 0 THEN 'Success'
               WHEN 1 THEN 'Failed'
               WHEN 4 THEN 'Hold/InQueue'
               WHEN 6 THEN 'Pending'
               WHEN 9 THEN 'Error'
               END
```